# Assign a value to object passed into class if value is null

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having trouble figuring out how to assign a value if no value is assigned to the object I am passing into this class.

I know this code looks a bit convoluted, but I wrote it as an example to answer my question.

The class simply assigns a numerical value to each letter in a string passed in as an object. Then pairs.generate will print the number associated with whatever letter is given. If a letter is given that is not in the dictionary created, it returns 0. Thus, if the dictionary is empty, 0 will be output for any letter given.

What I want to do is output a 0 if no object is passed in, but instead I receive the following error:
TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

To see what is working, pass the string "ABCD" in as an object and change the letter passed to pairs.generate(). To demonstrate what I want to happen when no object is passed, pass an empty string in (""). This will output 0 which is what I want to happen when no object is passed in instead of receiving the error message.

```
class Pairs(object):
def __init__(self, letters):
    print letters
    counter = 1
    d = {}
    for x in letters:
        d[x] = counter
        counter +=1

    self.d = d
    print self.d
    pass

def generate(self, letter):
    print "this is the key", letter
    if letter not in self.d:
        print "this key isn't in the dictionary:", letter
        return 0
    else:
        print "this is the value", self.d[letter]
        return self.d[letter]


enter = Pairs()
print enter.generate("F")
```

**Edit**
I have tried passing a default argument from my understanding. I tried a few ideas along the lines of:

```
class Plugboard(object):
    if object is None:
       object = ""
```

However, I am continuing to receive the same error.

Comment: your class requires the argument 'letters' which you aren't passing to it when you instantiate the class. enter = Pairs("abcdef")

Comment: @user2682863 I understand I am not passing an argument. I want my program to equate passing no argument with ""

Comment: you need to either explicitly pass "" or set the default argument value to ""

Comment: @user2682863 I tried passing a default argument, but I continue to receive the same error. See my edit above for an example. Can you please share an example code of a default argument that would work for my code?

Comment: object is not an argument, Object is the class that Pugboard inherits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either explicitly pass the argument required by your **init** method or add a default argument to **init**. Here is an example with the default argument included

```
class Pairs(object):
    def __init__(self, letters=""):  # added default value for letters
        print (letters)
        counter = 1
        d = {}
        for x in letters:
            d[x] = counter
            counter += 1

        self.d = d
        print(self.d)
        pass # this doesn't do anything

    def generate(self, letter):
        print ("this is the key", letter)
        if letter not in self.d:
            print ("this key isn't in the dictionary:", letter)
            return 0
        else:
            print ("this is the value", self.d[letter])
            return self.d[letter]


enter = Pairs() # this calls __init__, should pass 'letters'
print (enter.generate("F"))
```